# Passport-Azure-AD not validating access_token from MSAL Angular authentication

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

I have an Angular 10 app that I am using the MSAL-Angular package on to authenticate with Azure AD. It successfully authenticates and retrieves the `access_token` and `id_token` using the Authorization flow.

I also have an Express API backend that I am attaching the access_token to (using the Interceptor from `Msal-Angular`) onto the header of the request. I want to validate this token to verify that the Angular app has authenticated before allowing access to the api. To do this I am trying to use `passport-azure-ad` with the BearerStrategy. I believe I have it all setup correctly but it keeps telling me that the token can't be validated.

I figured out that if I use the `id_token` instead of `access_token` it can be verified; through the passport strategy and using jwt.io.

So the real question here is can I do something different in my config to validate the `access_token` that gets passed using `Msal-Angular` or should I just write my own Interceptor that sends the `id_token` instead of the `access_token`?

---

**API Passport config code** - *All I am trying to get done here is to get the passport validation to pass then will fill out the callback function.*

```
const options: IBearerStrategyOptionWithRequest = {
  identityMetadata:
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenet}.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration',
  clientID: '{my_client_id}',
  validateIssuer: true,
  loggingLevel: 'info',
  loggingNoPII: false,
  passReqToCallback: true,
};

const bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(options,
  function (req, token, done) {
    logger.debug(req);
    logger.debug(token);

    return done(null, { name: 'user name' }, token);
  });

passport.use(bearerStrategy);
```

Securing Route

```
function (req, res, next) {passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }),  listTasks);
```

Error given:

```
{
  "name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy",
  "hostname":"my_host",
  "pid":36344,
  "level":30,
  "msg":"authentication failed due to: invalid signature",
  "time":"2021-03-02T20:50:02.140Z",
  "v":0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it figured out. It was something to do with the scopes I was obtaining on the access_token. I was using `'user.read'`, and `'email'`, and when I switched over to using `'{client_id}/.default'` and the resulting token is able to be validated using the v1 well known metadata url.

I am still a little sketchy on scopes in general, but this is the page that I found that lead to the changes that fixed my problem.

[Scopes for a web API accepting v1.0 tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-v1-app-scopes#scopes-to-request-access-to-all-the-permissions-of-a-v10-application)

Comment: It might be better to specify scope as 'openid' . Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76873146/10030693